# Woocommerce Save Order button is not working for two orders

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders

[image]
I received two orders and order status is automatically set to on hold.
When the order was ready to deliver, I tried to change the order status to Pending Payment (as you see in the picture) but unfortunately the Save Order button is not working and it is not doing anything. I don't have any problem for the other orders. I have processed more than 100 orders without any problem. I couldn't find any difference between these orders and others that don't have any problem.
I found that I can change the order status to processing, on-hold or complete from the bulk edit (see below picture) but there is no Pending Payment option in bulk edit. 
[image]
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the problem.
The problem was because of the value with more than 1 decimal place in QTY field.

Comment: What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

@Majid Nasirinejad
I guess you are using the plug-in ***WooCommerce Advanced Quantity***.

I had the same issue and just found its cause.

Under "Edit Product" in the "Product data" section under 'WooCommerce Advanced Quantity' you can set "Minimum" and "Step" among others.

If in the 'Edit Order' page you edit the quantity and put any value outside those you defined in "Minimum" and "Step" etc., the "Update Button" will stop responding.

Solution:

e.g. Product C:
Weight (kg): 1

Minimum: 0.25
Step: 0.25

In this case, values allowed would be 0.25 - 0.50 - 0.75 - 1.00 - 1.25 etc.

if you put a value not covered by your settings, e.g. 0.4 or 1.17 your "Update Button" will not work.